# Dataframe operation within and between dataframes

Tags: r, database, dplyr

How can I make some operation within and between dataframes in R?

For example, here is a dataframe on stock returns.

```
stocks <- data.frame(
  time=as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9,
  X=rnorm(10, 0, 1),
  Y=rnorm(10, 0, 2),
  Z=rnorm(10, 0, 4)
)
         Date           X          Y           Z
1  2009-01-01 -0.31758501 -1.2718424  -2.9979292
2  2009-01-02 -1.06440187  0.4202969  -5.7925412
3  2009-01-03  0.26475736 -2.3955779  -2.2638179
4  2009-01-04 -0.83653746  0.4161053 -10.1011995
5  2009-01-05 -0.12214392  0.7143456   3.6851497
6  2009-01-06 -0.01186287 -2.1322029  -0.1577852
7  2009-01-07  0.27729415  0.1323237  -4.4237673
8  2009-01-08 -1.74389562  0.4962045   0.4192498
9  2009-01-09  0.83150240 -0.9241747  -1.6752324
10 2009-01-10 -0.52863956  0.1044531  -1.2083588
```

Q1) I'd like to create a dataframe with previous day.
    For example, final result that I want would be expressed lag(stocks,1)
    What is the most simple and elegant way to achieve this?
    Is there any simple way to use dplyr?

Q2) How can I apply any basic arithmetic operation to this dataframe?
    for example, I'd like to create dataframes with,

- stocks1 = stocks + 1
- stocks2 = stocks x 3
- stocks3 = stocks2 / stocks1 (operation between two dataframes)
- stocks4 = stocks3 / lag(stocks1)

Something like this.

What would be the most simple and elegant way?

Comment: Why don't you show us what you've tried, maybe it's not that inelegant?

Comment: I tried but only to fail. For example, stocks[,2:4] + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the first problem, this might be of help to you. You don't necessarily need to use **dplyr** in this instance, using the **head()** function should be sufficient if all you wish to do is lag the variables.

```
stocks <- data.frame(
  time=as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9,
  X=rnorm(10, 0, 1),
  Y=rnorm(10, 0, 2),
  Z=rnorm(10, 0, 4)
)

previous<-head(stocks,9)
df<-data.frame(stocks$time[2:10],stocks$X[2:10],stocks$Y[2:10],stocks$Z[2:10],previous$X,previous$Y,previous$Z)
col_headings<-c("time","X","Y","Z","previousX","previousY","previousZ")
names(df)<-col_headings
```

Here, the dates from 2nd January to 10th January are displayed, with the lags for X, Y, and Z also being included in the data frame.

```
> df
        time          X          Y           Z  previousX  previousY
1 2009-01-02  0.7878110 -2.1394047  0.68775794 -0.0759606  1.2863089
2 2009-01-03 -0.2767296 -2.3453356 -1.56313888  0.7878110 -2.1394047
3 2009-01-04 -0.2122021  0.1589629 -1.13926020 -0.2767296 -2.3453356
4 2009-01-05  0.1195826  3.2320352 -0.32020803 -0.2122021  0.1589629
5 2009-01-06  0.7642622 -0.7621168  1.66614679  0.1195826  3.2320352
6 2009-01-07 -0.3073972 -2.9475654  5.63945611  0.7642622 -0.7621168
7 2009-01-08  0.3597369  0.5011861  5.95424269 -0.3073972 -2.9475654
8 2009-01-09 -1.8701881  0.4417496  1.34273218  0.3597369  0.5011861
9 2009-01-10 -1.1172033 -0.5566736  0.05432339 -1.8701881  0.4417496
   previousZ
1  3.2188050
2  0.6877579
3 -1.5631389
4 -1.1392602
5 -0.3202080
6  1.6661468
7  5.6394561
8  5.9542427
9  1.3427322
```

As regards calculations, it depends on what you are trying to do.

e.g. do you want to add **1** to each row in Z?

```
> df$Z+1
[1]  1.6877579 -0.5631389 -0.1392602  0.6797920  2.6661468  6.6394561
[7]  6.9542427  2.3427322  1.0543234
```

You could divide two stock returns by each other as you've specified as well. Note that we have combined them in the one dataframe, so we are not necessarily conducting an "operation between two dataframes" per se.

```
> df$Y/df$Z
[1]  -3.11069421   1.50040132  -0.13953168 -10.09354826  -0.45741275
[6]  -0.52266839   0.08417294   0.32899307 -10.24740160
```

By specifying the dataframe (in this case, df), along with the associated variable (as indicated after the $ symbol), then you should be able to carry out a wide range of calculations across the dataframe.